# Is globalalloc with GMEM_MOVEABLE dangerous for local variables in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, memory, gdi+, tms

Our programming dept just spent about a non-mythical man-month tracking down what we think is a bug in a 3rd party component, here's their copyrighted source code:

```
function TGDIPPicture.GetImageSizes: boolean;
var
  multi: TGPImage;
  pstm: IStream;
  hGlobal: THandle;
  pcbWrite: Longint;

begin
  result := false;

  if Empty then
    Exit;

  if FDataStream.Size = 0 then
    Exit;

  hGlobal := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, FDataStream.Size);
  if (hGlobal = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not allocate memory for image');


  try
    pstm := nil;
    // Create IStream* from global memory
    CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, TRUE, pstm);
    pstm.Write(FDataStream.Memory, FDataStream.Size,@pcbWrite);
    multi := TGPImage.Create(pstm);

    FWidth := multi.GetWidth;
    FHeight := multi.GetHeight;

    Result := true;

    multi.Free;
  finally
    GlobalFree(hGlobal);
  end;

end;
```

We found the problem was with TMS's AdvOfficeTabSet. If we added tabs, then it crashed, if we didn't add tabs then it didn't crash.  (the crash was one of those un-debuggable app hangs that hits you 10 steps after the real problem).

Following [Raymond Chen's advice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/09/254441.aspx) I replaced GMEM_MOVEABLE with GPTR and <s>it appears to have fixed the problem.</s>

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if the above code had any legitimate reason for using GMEM_MOVEABLE. AFAIK it's only for the clipboard and it should always be used with GlobalAlloc.

---

while I was typing this another programmer got an error in the GlobalFree function using my code.  So, apparently this doesn't work either.  Could really use some help here!

*CreateStreamOnHGlobal is a Windows API function. (which apparently [prefers GMEM_MOVEABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

*TGPImage is part of TMS's implementation of the GDI+ library.

Comment: You're passing `TRUE` to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()` for the `fDeleteOnRelease` parameter which means the stream now owns the memory handle, and you shouldn't call `GlobalFree()` yourself. You also don't seem to be releasing the stream (unless Delphi does this for you automatically, or maybe `TGPImage.Create` does? If so you'll **definitely** end up with a double free of the memory handle). Whether these things are causing your crash I don't know, but there's no inherent problem in using `GMEM_MOVEABLE` in this situation so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Comment: Is this the real code? It's got loads of problems. Not assigning result value. Missing error checks. And so on. How can we be sure that GlobalAlloc is even the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's what we're about to try with our 3rd attempt at using a function we'd rather not use at all!  I tried changing the TRUE to false in CreateStreamOnHGlobal and hit different problems, some realloc thing, hopefully what you said is the right and only answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah, it's from TMS, I'd imagine I'm infringing on some copyright by posting this, but it should be fixed and it's not novel enough to care about the copyright. I'd rather just not use globals if possible - it wouldn't be too much for me to change.

Comment: Very hard to believe TMS wrote that. It's tripe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, my bad, I was twiddling with it and forgot the default result value, but other than that it's verbatim

Comment: @Jonathan FWIW Delphi manages interface variables. As variables are copied, come out of scope etc., AddRef and Release calls are written by the compiler. So the interface is indeed released.

Answer (score 3):

Jonathan has identified the obvious problem, that being the double free of the HGLOBAL. But as you have found, the use is GMEM_MOVEABLE is correct.

Frankly, the code seems needlessly complex. I suggest you use the built in stream adapter and avoid any GlobalAlloc. To get an IStream you just need to do this:

```
pstm := TStreamAdapter.Create(FDataStream);
```

That's it.

Comment: Well, it compiled! I wound up with a seriously odd looking close button on my tabs. There were about 20 similar functions to what was above in all of the pack I got from TMS, two of them appeared to have correct (non double freeing) implementations, maybe I'll just leave them alone.